# Unable to add Azure AD admin user to Enterprise Admins group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to find a way to add a Azure admin user to the Enterprise Admins group of a Azure AD domain to allow me to manage features of AD users which I can't manage via Azure AD.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/faqs#do-i-have-domain-administrator-privileges-for-the-managed-domain-provided-by-azure-ad-domain-services

> Do I have domain administrator privileges for the managed domain provided by Azure AD Domain Services?
>
> No. You aren't granted administrative privileges on the managed
>   domain. Domain Administrator and Enterprise Administrator privileges
>   aren't available for you to use within the domain. Members of the
>   domain administrator or enterprise administrator groups in your
>   on-premises Active Directory are also not granted domain / enterprise
>   administrator privileges on the managed domain.

So as per that, I would say this is probably not possible.